# How to set properly rowsep when using multicell on tabularray package?

Tags: tabularray

I needed to adjust the abovesep/belowsep on my table from the `tabularray` package so the content is more compressed. However, it does not affect the multirow cells. Why this happens?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{
width=\textwidth,
colspec = {X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m,wd=1cm]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
row{1-Z} = {font=\scriptsize},
row{even} = {bg=gray9},
abovesep = -2pt,
belowsep = -1pt,
row{2} = {abovesep = 0pt},
}
\hline[.8pt] 
\textbf{Study} & \textbf{Sessions} & \textbf{Age} & \textbf{Time lapse} & \textbf{People per ss} & \textbf{Images per person per ss} & \textbf{Impressions per ss} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Total images} & \textbf{Local} \\\hline
\cite{jain2014recognizing} & 5 & 0-4y & 1w & 20 & 16 & 4 & T and If (L,R) & 1600 & USA \\
\cite{jain2014recognizing} & 5 & 0-4y & 1w & 20 & 16 & 4 & T and If (L,R) & 1600 & USA \\
\SetCell[r=3]{m} \cite{jain2016fingerprint} & 4 & 0-5 (2.0)y & {6m\\ 4m\\ 2m} & {204\\ 167\\ 180\\ 178} & {6\\ 12\\ 12\\ 12} & \SetCell[r=3]{m} 3 & \SetCell[r=3]{m}T (L,R) x 2sc & {1224\\ 2004\\ 2160\\ 2136} & \SetCell[r=3]{m} India \\
 & 3 & 0-42 (6.1)w & {4m\\ 2m} & {65\\ 52\\ 50} & 12 &  &  & {780\\ 624\\ 600} &  \\
 & 2 & 0-42 (7.6)w & 2m & {40\\ 30} & 12 &  &  & {480\\ 360} &  \\
{\cite{jain2016giving} \cite{koda2016advances}} & 2 & 0-6m & 2-4d & 66 & 6 & 3 & T (L,R) & 792 & India \\
\cite{camacho2017recognizing} & 2 & 0-10 (3.36)y & 4.6-20 (12.28)m & $>$= 45395 & $>$=1 & 1 & T and If (at least) & 45395 pairs & Uruguay \\
\hline[.7pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```